# Ionic gives prompt: Acquire a developer license, Install the signing certificate

Tags: node.js, windows, ionic2

I'm using Ionic to build a windows app but after running command ***ionic run windows*** I got following log:

```
Before installing this app, you need to do the following:


        - Acquire a developer license


        - Install the signing certificate


Administrator credentials are required to continue.  Please accept the UAC prompt and provide your administrator password if asked.


Press Enter to continue...:
```

Then after it stops and no keypress event is listened in the console.

When I run cmd with admin privilege. It gives following error:

```
Error: Can not run this platform with administrative permissions. Must be run from a non-admin prompt.
```

Comment: Try to run cmd as admin...

Comment: started giving shell.js: internal error
Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, error

Comment: I think the error is more verbose, maybe you could add this to your question..?

Comment: Did my solution help?

Answer (score 1):

### **Solution 1:**

Run the command

```
ionic run windows
```

in **PowerShell** and it works like a charm (no admin rights).

### **Solution 2:**

You can also go to

```
[project path]\platforms\windows\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_0.0.1.0_anycpu_debug_Test
```

and right click on the *.ps1 file

```
Add-AppDevPackage.ps1
```

and click **Run with PowerShell**

Hope this helps!

PS: Don't forget to add

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
```

to the config.xml file, as documented [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/platform-setup/windows-setup.html).